# Win + Python3.6で「pip install」を実行したときに「UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83」と表示される。

Tags: python, windows, 機械学習, anaconda, chainer

実行環境：
Python3, PyCharm
ライブラリ関係が必要とのことで、Anacondaを入れ直しました。

[結月ゆかりに機械学習で声質変換するスクリプト](https://github.com/Hiroshiba/become-yukarin)の`Readme.md`に従って、音響特徴量の切り出しをしようとコードを実行するも、PyCharmが立ち上がってしまいます。別なコードを実行してみても、PyCharmが立ち上がってしまいます。

ふと気づいたので、関連付けがPyCharmになっていたので、Pythonに変更しました。
実行できましたが以下のエラーが出ます。

```
ModuleNotFoundError :  No Module Named 'become_yukarin'
```

Pythonのモジュールの説明を見ていて気づいたのですが、ディレクトリ図の

> > become_yukarin  # このディレクトリは外から使えることを想定

これが関係ありますか？このディレクトリにパスを通す必要がありますか？パスを通してみましたが、エラー結果は同じです。

音響特徴量の切り出しスクリプトであるextract_acoustic_feature.py  # 音響特徴量切り出しですが、PyCharmで見る限り、冒頭部分の、

```
import numpy

from become_yukarin.acoustic_converter import AcousticConverter
from become_yukarin.config.config import create_from_json as create_config
from become_yukarin.data_struct import AcousticFeature
from become_yukarin.dataset.dataset import AcousticFeatureLoadProcess
from become_yukarin.dataset.dataset import AcousticFeatureProcess
from become_yukarin.dataset.dataset import AcousticFeatureSaveProcess
from become_yukarin.dataset.dataset import WaveFileLoadProcess
from become_yukarin.dataset.utility import MFCCAligner
from become_yukarin.param import AcousticFeatureParam
from become_yukarin.param import VoiceParam
```

で引っかかっているようです。numpyはAnacondaで入ったはずですが、呼び出せてないようです。あと頭にbecame_yukarinがあるそのフォルダにあるパッケージ化されたスクリプトも呼び出せていないようです。

なのでエラーを吐いて止まってしまうのでは無いかと考えました。

```
├── become_yukarin  # このディレクトリは外から使えることを想定
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py  # 学習の設定パラメータ
│   ├── data_struct.py  # データ構造の定義
│   ├── dataset
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── dataset.py  # データ処理
│   │   └── utility.py
│   ├── model.py  # ニューラルネットワーク構造
│   ├── param.py  # 音声パラメータ
│   ├── updater.py  # chainerのUpdater
│   └── voice_changer.py  # 学習済みモデルを使って声質変換
├── recipe
│   ├── config.json  # 学習の設定パラメータ
│   └── recipe.json  # 複数の学習を回す時のパラメータ
├── requirements.txt  # 依存関係のあるライブラリ
├── scripts
│   ├── extract_acoustic_feature.py  # 音響特徴量切り出し
│   ├── launch.py  # 複数の学習を回す
│   ├── ln_apply_subset.py
│   ├── ln_atr503_to_subset.py
│   ├── ln_jnas_subset.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_dataset.py
└── train.py  # 学習用のスクリプト
```

回答1を参考にして考えました。

[PythonのPathについて](http://blog1.erp2py.com/2010/10/pythonpath.html)によれば、

> > Pythonを使い始めた頃、Path設定がよくわからなかった。
> >     あるモジュールをインポートして使いたいのだけど、使えない。どうもPathが通っていないようだという事はわかったのだが、Pathと言えばWindowsだと思っていたのでWindows設定を変更していた。でも動かない・・・。
> >
> > 実はPythonの実行マシン内にPath設定を持っていたのでした（笑）。

ということで、Windowsのユーザー環境変数のPYTHONPATHに設定する必要があるようです。

それで、PYTHONPATHをbecome_yukarinに通しましたが、同じエラーが出ます。

become_yukarinの上のディレクトリにPYTHONPATHを通してみたところ、パッケージbecome_yukarinが見つからないとのエラーは回避できました。

今度はchainerがないとのエラーが出ました。

[Chainerのインストール方法をわかりやすく解説｜Mac・Linux・Windows](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/42488#AnacondaChainer)を参考に、
試したところ、もうChainerはインストールされているようです。

```
pip uninstall Chainer
```

でChainerをいったんアンインストールしました。
    pip install chainer
でChainerを再びインストールしました。
結果は変わりなしです。

PythonとAnacondaをアンインストールして、Anacondaを入れ直し、chainerを入れ直したところ何もエラーが出なくなりました。

やはり関連付けがPycahrmになっていたので変更しました。

librosaが無いとのエラーが出ました。
    pip install librosa
で入れました。

pysptkがないとのエラーが出ました。
    pip install pysptk
で入れようとしたら、赤字のエラーが大量に出ます。
　　　　
[Win + Python3.6で「pip install」を実行したときに「UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83」と表示される。](https://qiita.com/ruteshi_SI_shiteru/items/be6a58276bdbd67dc096)を参考に修正してみました。追記2行コメントアウト4行でエラーメッセージに変化が見られましたが、インストールはできないです。

参考
ディープラーニングの力で結月ゆかりの声になってみた
https://hiroshiba.github.io/blog/became-yuduki-yukari-with-deep-learning-power/

Answer (score 2):

そのリポジトリの作者です。
`become_yukarin`ライブラリの親ディレクトリにパスを通す必要があります。
以下詳細です。

ファイル構造は多分こうなっていると思います。

become_yukarin（親ディレクトリ）
└become_yukarin（モジュールのディレクトリ）
　└`__init__.py`
　└他
└scripts
　└色々
└他

親ディレクトリに対してパス（環境変数PATHではなく、PYTHONPATH）を通す必要があります。
https://docs.python.jp/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

pythonは日本語のドキュメントがあります。なんだかんだ役に立つと思います。
https://docs.python.jp/3/using/

Comment: ディレクトリ図のbecome_yukarin  # このディレクトリは外から使えることを想定が親ディレクトリと言うことでしょうか？

Comment: いやこれはモジュールのディレクトリですね。その上にはbecome-yukarin-masterがあります。これにPYTHONPATH通せば良いのですかね。